# How are files created during FTP?

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp, open, mkdir

When one uses FTP/SFTP on Linux, is the method the server uses to create directories and files `mkdir` and `open` or something else entirely?

Comment: Let me ask you a question - you really think mkdir creates a directory WITHOUT USING ANOTHER API? One lower level? After all, it is a shell command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it probably does use [mkdir(2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir)) and [open(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) (or something very similar).

You could check by running [strace(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) on your ftp daemon and exercising it e.g.

```
strace -p <pid of ftp daemon>
```